# How to Test Value Returned in Promise from AngularJS Controller with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise, q

I have a controller that expose a function that returns some text after a rest call.  It works fine, but I'm having trouble testing it with Jasmine.  **The code inside the promise handler in the test never executes**.

The controller:

```
/* global Q */
'use strict';
angular.module('myModule', ['some.service'])
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'SomeSvc', function ($scope, SomeSvc) {

        $scope.getTheData = function (id) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            var processedResult = '';
            SomeSvc.getData(id)
                .then(function (result) {
                    //process data
                    processedResult = 'some stuff';
                    deferred.resolve(processedResult);
                })
                .fail(function (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }]);
```

The test:

```
describe('some tests', function() {
    var $scope;
    var $controller;
    var $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myModule');
        inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_) {
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $controller = _$controller_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            //mock the call that the SomeSvc call from the controller will make
            $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'the/url/to/my/data');
            $httpBackend.whenGET('the/url/to/my/data')
                .respond({data:'lots of data'});
            $controller ('MyCtrl', {
                $scope: $scope
            });
        });
    });

    describe('test the returned value from the promise', function() {
        var prom = $scope.getTheData(someId);
        prom.then(function(result) {
            expect(result).toBe('something expected');  //this code never runs
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: What are the symptoms? Any errors?

Comment: @alecxe the symptoms are that the code inside the then never runs, so I cant make an assertion.  Updated the code and question to better reflect the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why you're using `Q` and not `$q`? And what sort of promise does `SomeSvc.getData` return: one created using `$q` (such as those returned from `$http`), or one from `Q`)?

Comment: This project uses big Q rather than the provided $q with Angular, because $q was missing something that Q provided.  The design decision was made a while back, and I dont recall the details at the moment.  Both promises in question return a promise created by big Q.

Comment: Looks like you use the [Deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) (although hardly the reason for your problems)

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: This could have had such an easy answer: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything inside a `then` will not be run unless the promise callbacks are called - which is a risk for a false positive like you experienced here. **The test will pass here since the expect was never run.**

There are many ways to make sure you don't get a false positive like this. Examples:

### A) Return the promise

Jasmine will wait for the promise to be resolved within the timeout.

- If it is not resolved in time, the test will fail.
- If the promise is rejected, the test will also fail.

**Beware** If you forget the return, your test will give a false positive!

```
describe('test the returned value from the promise', function() {
    return $scope.getTheData(someId)
    .then(function(result) {
        expect(result).toBe('something expected');
    });
});
```

### B) Use the `done` callback provided by Jasmine to the test method

- If `done` is not called within the timeout the test will fail.
- If `done` is called with arguments the test will fail.
  The catch here will pass the error to jasmine and you will see the error
  in the output.

**Beware** If you forget the catch, your error will be swallowed and your test will fail with a generic timeout error.

```
describe('test the returned value from the promise', function(done) {
    $scope.getTheData(someId)
    .then(function(result) {
        expect(result).toBe('something expected');
        done();
    })
    .catch(done);
});
```

### C) Using spies and hand cranking (synchronous testing)

If you're not perfect this might be the safest way to write tests.

```
it('test the returned value from the promise', function() {
    var
      data = { data: 'lots of data' },
      successSpy = jasmine.createSpy('success'),
      failureSpy = jasmine.createSpy('failure');

    $scope.getTheData(someId).then(successSpy, failureSpy);

    $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'the/url/to/my/data').respond(200, data);
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(successSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data);
    expect(failureSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**Synchronous testing tricks**
You can hand crank httpBackend, timeouts and changes to scope when needed to get the controller/services to go *one step further*. `$httpBackend.flush()`, `$timeout.flush()`, `scope.$apply()`.

Comment: `. So don't use expect inside then in tests.` That is terrible advise. Learn to use your frameworks general support for testing async code instead. Jasmine: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support Mocha: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Your comment isn't informative. If you have a better answer, answer the question with your own answer. The Jasmine docs specifically do not use ".then" on any of it's tests. The answer was provided in 2014, perhaps something has changed. I still believe it is a really bad idea to put expects in ".then". Prove me wrong.

Comment: Not informative? I linked directly to the doc sections on async testing of the two most popular test frameworks to show how it's done. The code you are testing is async, yet you just provide synchronous imperatives. The point here is that Promises belong to the async dimension, so even though the docs does not use promises (or generators, async/await, etc ...) it shows how to do async test programming. That involves passing the `done` parameter to the async part of the test. In promises, that is in the callback to a `Thenable`. As in: `doSomething().then(done).catch(done)`.

Comment: I look forward to all StackOverflow answers being replaced with links to docs mate. ;) It is easy to write the test with cleaner code, everyone learns over the years, but not by reading the Jasmine docs you linked to, they're useless in this case imo.

Comment: Well whatever the case, your answer is much better now :-) Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

In case there is a promise created by `$q` somewhere (and since you seem to be using $httpBackend, then this might well be the case), then my suggestions are to trigger a digest cycle after the call to `getTheData`, and make sure that the call to `expect` isn't in a `then` callback (so that if something is broken, the test fails, rather than just not run).

```
var prom = $scope.getTheData(someId);
$scope.$apply();
expect(result).toBe('something expected');
```

The reason this might help is that Angular promises are tied to the digest cycle, and their callbacks are only called if a digest cycle runs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is that you are testing async code (promise based) using synchronous code. That won't work, as the test has finished before the `Thenable` in your test code has started running the callback containing the test. The [Jasmine docs specifically show how to test async code](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) (same [as Mocha](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)), and the fix is very small:

```
describe('test the returned value from the promise', function(done) {
    var prom = $scope.getTheData(someId);
    prom.then(function(result) {
        expect(result).toBe('something expected');  //this code never runs
        done(); // the signifies the test was successful
    }).catch(done); // catches any errors
});
```

Comment: I don't believe jasmine made this available at the time the question was posted.  And/or the project was not able to bumpthe jasmine version that did allow for "done".

Comment: @binarygiant Since asynchronicity is such a big part of every javascript project Jasmine has of course had support for async testing since the start :-) Jasmine 1.0 used `runs`, `waits` and `waitsFor`, while Jasmine 2.0 (introduced in 2013) aligned with Mocha in just using a callback to accomplish the same. See https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html

Comment: Yup, that's great.  The question was answered several years ago.  Are we flexing our condescending muscles here?

Comment: Jeesus, man, no need to get your panties in a bunch! I was not trying to be condescending, and if it came out like that I apologize. This is the top Q&A site just by the pure fact that answers are continually refined. The accepted was incorrect, and so I added a correct one. The accepted one has now been improved. This is practice is _encouraged_, as people still find older questions when googling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  You do sound condescending and arrogant.  Work on that.

Comment: Thanks for nothing.